Ask for s3fs-fuse synchronize
I installed s3fs-fuse on the centos server and I have a question about synchronization.
The current situation is that Object Storage is synchronized with the CentOS server.
I'm asking if every time a file is uploaded from Object Storage, synchronization continues in the directory mounted on CentOS? Or if synchronization occurs when a real user accesses the uploaded directory.
I'm asking because of the server's performance, because if S3FS-FUSE synchronizes every time there is an I/O in Object Storage, the server's performance can be problematic. Thank you.
Can i use TCP Dump?? or not

s3fs is a file system, not a file synchronization tool.  This means that it sends file operations to the server as the application generates them.  However these operations are buffered until the application calls fsync, close, or the dirty data reaches a limit, controlled by -o max_dirty_data.  If you want to synchronize files please use another tool like rclone.
